# How to create a JSON controller in odoo?

Tags: json, odoo, odoo-8

I'm googling docs on how to create a json view on odoo, but find litle info

I need to create a json view to access from javascript.

I'm trying like this:

```
@http.route('/test/status/<name>', auth='public', type='json')
    def temp(self, name,**kwargs):

        return [{'status': 'test',
                 }]
```

Javascript code:

```
function check_status() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    $.getJSON("/test/status/" + name +"/",
            function(data){
                var status = data.status;
                $('#msg').text(status);
    });
};
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
<function temp at 0x7f1a8b7d5140>, /test/status/lego/: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'json' but called with a request of type 'http'
```

Please help i'm stuck

[edit for answer @odoo_user2]

```
function json_function_name() {
        odoo.define('custom_webpage.my_js', function (require) {'use strict';
            var ajax = require('web.ajax');
            ajax.jsonRpc('/pa/get_models/' + variable_id, 'call', {}).then(function (data) {
                if (data.models == false) {
                } else {
                    // load models
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.models.length; i++) {
                        var opt = document.createElement('option');
                        opt.innerHTML = data.models[i][1];
                        opt.value = data.models[i][0];
                        sel_models.appendChild(opt);
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    }
}
```

this is the javascript function I use, and the controller:

```
@http.route('/pa/get_models/<brand_id>', auth='none', type='json',website=True)
def get_models(self,brand_id**kwargs):
    cr = http.request._cr
    res = utils.get_models(cr,int(brand_id))
    return {'models': res,}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use '@json' instead of '@http'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `$.getJSON` use  `openerp.jsonRpc` in odoo8 and `var ajax = require('web.ajax');`  `ajax.jsonRpc` in odoo9 .

Comment: Ok, I doing that and now I get response, but I've to change the controllers like: 
class odoo_test(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/test/status/<name>', auth='none', type='json')
    def temp(self, name,**kwargs):
        status = 'status test'
        status_p = 5

        res = {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
               "method": "call",
               "params": {
                 'status':status,
                 'status_p':status_p,
                 },
                "id": None,
                }

        return JsonRequest(res)
and get the 'dict' object has no attribute 'session' error

Comment: solve: I need to return:
res = {'status':status,
               'status_p':status_p,
                 }

        return res

Comment: @MarianoDAngelo Do you create Json contoller, can you share code?

Answer (score 2):

Currently I'm working on python web controller which returns json. I'll give you little example:

```
from openerp import http, _
from openerp.http import request
import json

class ClassName(http.Controller):
    @http.route('url', auth='user', type="json")
    def className(self, **kw):
        cr = request.cr
        context = request.context
        uid = request.uid
        user = request.env['res.users'].sudo().browse(uid)
        # now in kw you have all arguments from your post request
        # and finally when you will finish work with data and want to
        # return json return like that
        return json.dumps(res)
        # where res is dictionary
```

Also I recommend to make input validation in python web controller its more secure!
Mark this answer as correct answer it this is what you need. (I think this is what you need)

Comment: Darchiashvill Hello, Can you share full example?

Answer (score 0):

Check this JS call [1]

```
openerp.jsonRpc('/website/check_gengo_set', 'call',[...]
```

with its controller [2]

```
@http.route('/website/check_gengo_set', type='json', auth='user', website=True)
```

And this works, so for some reason maybe you are not doing a proper JSON request.

The error is triggered here [3] and pops up just for that: the request does not match the type.

Note that `jsonrpc` call does this [4]:

```
openerp.jsonRpc = function(url, fct_name, params, settings) {
    return genericJsonRpc(fct_name, params, function(data) {
        return $.ajax(url, _.extend({}, settings, {
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data, date_to_utc),
            contentType: 'application/json'
        }));
    });
};
```

Anyway, if you want to use that JS maybe you can try w/ `type="http"` and dump json yourself. That should work.

[1] https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/8.0/addons/website_gengo/static/src/js/website_gengo.js#L42

[2] https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/8.0/addons/website_gengo/controllers/main.py#L21

[3] https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/8.0/openerp/http.py#L290

[4] https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/8.0/addons/web/static/src/js/openerpframework.js#L859